# How can I use Mockito to test this function?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mockito

I'm trying to test that Permission.REVEAL_NOW returns the method isFeatureRevealNowAvailable.
Heres some code I already tried but didn't succeed with. Any help would be hugely appreciated as always!

Function to test:

```
class PermissionRepository(private val permissionApi: PermissionApi,    
                       private val appPreferences: AppPreferences) {

fun checkPermission(permission: PermissionType, onPermissionResponse: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    Log.i("Permission", "Checking permission")
    when (permission) {
        PermissionType.REVEAL_NOW -> {
            isFeatureRevealNowAvailable(onPermissionResponse, ::errorHandler)
        }
    }
}
```

Attempted solution:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class PermissionRepositoryTest{

@Test
fun checkPermissionTest() {
    val mockPermissionRepository = mock(PermissionRepository::class.java)
    val mockPermissionApi = mock(PermissionApi::class.java)
    val result = mockPermissionRepository.checkPermission(PermissionType.REVEAL_NOW, onPermissionResponse = null)

    //Unsure of what to use here AssertThat or Mockito's "when" function


}
```

}

```
private fun isFeatureRevealNowAvailable(permissionResponseHandler: (Boolean) -> Unit, permissionError: (Throwable) -> Unit) {

    permissionApi.getRevealNowPermission().enqueue(object : Callback<PermissionResponse> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<PermissionResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            permissionResponseHandler(false)
            permissionError(t)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<PermissionResponse>, response: Response<PermissionResponse>) {
            val permissionResult = response.body()?.isRevealNow ?: false

            updateUserLocalPermission(PermissionType.REVEAL_NOW, permissionResult)

            permissionResponseHandler(permissionResult)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Plase show what `isFeatureRevealNowAvailable(onPermissionResponse, ::errorHandler)` does. I can't see what your method is influencing and your test name doesn't tell anything about expectation or output. Define what you want to happen - invocation / entity saved / return result / ...

Comment: Updated to show that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(TL;DR - go to **Example**)

Since you don't define specifically what you want to test or achieve, I will give some overall tips:

### Mocking

- Never mock the class you want to test

  `val mockPermissionRepository = mock(PermissionRepository::class.java)`
- Mock only what you want to exclude from your test but rely on
- Try to avoid mocks whenever it is possible and makes sence, because they simulate a perfect world, not the real behaviour

### Test naming

Use proper names to describe what you want to achive with your test. My personal favourite is to start the sentence with the word "should ..."

### Example

Two tests I could image to write for your function:

```
@Test
    fun `should invoke reveal permission on PermissionApi when type is REVEAL_NOW`(){
    val mockPermissionApi = mock(PermissionApi::class.java)
    val permissionRepository = PermissionRepository(mockPermissionApi, mock())

    permissionRepository.checkPermission(PermissionType.REVEAL_NOW, onPermissionResponse = {})

    verify(mockPermissionApi, times(1)).getRevealNowPermission()
}

@Test
fun `should do nothing when type is not REVEAL_NOW`() {
    val mockPermissionApi = mock(PermissionApi::class.java)
    val permissionRepository = PermissionRepository(mockPermissionApi, mock())

    permissionRepository.checkPermission(PermissionType.ELSE, onPermissionResponse = {})

    verify(mockPermissionApi, times(0)).getRevealNowPermission()
}
```